# angular grid selected checkbox scroll issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have a column with a `celltemplate` of `checkbox`. It can be selected/unselected, which works fine as correct events are fired everytime. However, when I select multiple checkboxes on the grid and start scrolling up and down, the checkboxes seem to be scrolling as well. That means that they are not fixed to the rows they are checked against, and get lined up against a wrong row.

This issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1427) a couple of years ago. But the solution posted, does not solve the problem.

Here is a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/w5m44AkIQAmVpehL3HDM) to demonstrate the issue. Anyone had any similar issue or a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not binding the checkboxvalue to your dataset. Thanks to your provided Plunker I can provide an [updated Version](http://plnkr.co/edit/qd2qYOyv1mQeBlitZSqe?p=preview) that works.

The ng-model is bound to the gridscope and has a private scope for each row, so its fine to use somethnig generic

`ng-model="foo" ng-change="row.entity.active = foo"`

You can use `active == 1` but I used true/false for convenience

`ng-checked="row.entity.active" //since foo becomes true or false on click`

If you want more complex checks, you can use their `appScopeProvider`.